# How to return two lists to chartjs from Django View

Tags: django, list, chart.js

I am using chartjs to render a barchart. For this I need to pass two lists in the format like [1, 2, 3] & [3, 2, 1]. I am making an AJAX call to Django which returns the two lists (I have not added the code to get the data from the database yet). The graph works fine for one list but not sure how to pass the second list.

I tried to pass the two lists as json and tried to use each of the lists in the success function of the ajax call but the graph does not render properly. With one list the graph is working fine

below is the code for the ChartJs AJAX call

```
$.ajax({  
    async: pasys,  
    type: "GET",  
    url: purl,  
    data: pdata,  
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
    dataType: "json",  
    success: function(ldata) {  
        var barData = {  
        labels: ["Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct",   
                  "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar"],  
        datasets: [  
        {  
            label: "DL1",  
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.5)',    
            pointBorderColor: "#fff",  
            data: ldata.data1  
        },  
        {  
            label: "Non-DL1",  
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(100, 200, 300, 0.5)',  
            pointBorderColor: "#aaa",  
            data: ldata.data2  
         }  
       ]  
     };

     var barOptions = { 
         responsive: true
     };

     var ctx2 = 
       document.getElementById("opendemandtrend").getContext("2d");
       new Chart(ctx2, {type: 'bar', data: barData, options:barOptions});
```

*** below is the code for the django view ***

```
    def gldh_productivitymetric_opendemandtrend_get(request):  
    lcompanyid = request.GET.get("pcompanyid")  
    lpmid      = request.GET.get("ppmid")  

    data = json.dumps({"data1": "[12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]",  
                       "data2": "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]"})  

    return HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing in strings as the values, instead of lists. Don't do that.

```
data = json.dumps({"data1": [12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],  
                   "data2": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]})
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel. It worked. I am able to plot the graph as expected. Much appreciate the help.